# Image Gallery on Android 3

Tags: android

I run this program it is show normally but when I click this image or scroll this image it is crashed.Please Help me!

**My code Here:**  [enter link description here](http://codepad.org/0ddQgAb5)

**My Error:**

```
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:616)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:349)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.example.gallerycookbook.GalleryImageAdapter.getView(GalleryImageAdapter.java:47)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:865)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRightLtr(Gallery.java:819)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRight(Gallery.java:763)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.Gallery.trackMotionScroll(Gallery.java:393)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.Gallery.onScroll(Gallery.java:1043)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:572)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.widget.Gallery.onTouchEvent(Gallery.java:958)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line shows the problem :

```
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 14:18:56.064: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

from oracle doc :

Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector. OutOfMemoryError objects may be constructed by the virtual machine as if suppression were disabled and/or the stack trace was not writable.

use this code to down scale your picture :

```
private Bitmap downscaleBitmapUsingDensities(final int sampleSize,final int imageResId)
  {
  final Options bitmapOptions=new Options();
  bitmapOptions.inDensity=sampleSize;
  bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity=1;
  final Bitmap scaledBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageResId,bitmapOptions);
  scaledBitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
  return scaledBitmap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran out of memory. This is usually when you try to show many images in one view. You should use bitmaps efficiently. One way to do it would be to use library like Universal Image loader which uses lazyloading. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open image that fill whole memory that android gave to process. To avoid it you have to down sample image before show it. I suggest to use very cool library - [Android Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/).